# Is there any alternative to Vertica's conditional_true_event in RedShift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, vertica

Vertica has a very nice type of operations: [Event-Based Window operations](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/Event-basedWindows.htm), which basically let you identify when an event occurs.
For example the conditional_true_event will increment a counter each time the given boolean expression resolves to true.
We use this kind of approach heavily.

We are thinking about moving to RedShift, but we would need a similar function.
RedShift has some nice [window functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html), but I can't find this one.

Is there any way I can emulate this function using RedShift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT()` is rather easy to write with window functions. It's just a `COUNT` with a conditional (`CASE`):

```
SELECT ts, symbol, bid,
       CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(bid > 10.6)  
           OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS oce
FROM Tickstore3 
ORDER BY ts ;
```

becomes:

```
SELECT ts, symbol, bid,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN bid > 10.6 THEN 1 END)  
           OVER (ORDER BY ts
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS oce
FROM Tickstore3 
ORDER BY ts ;
```

---

The `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT()` is more complicated because it needs to use the previous value. It can be emulated using `LAG()` and `SUM()` or `COUNT()` (or `ROW_NUMBER()`). But it will require I think a CTE or a derived table (or a self-join):

```
SELECT ts, symbol, bid,
       CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(bid)  
           OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS cce
FROM Tickstore3 
ORDER BY ts ;
```

will become:

```
WITH emu AS
  ( SELECT ts, symbol, bid,
           CASE WHEN bid <> LAG(bid) OVER (ORDER BY ts) 
               THEN 1 
           END AS change_bid
    FROM Tickstore3
  ) 
SELECT ts, symbol, bid,
       COUNT(change_bid) 
           OVER (ORDER BY ts
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
         AS cce
FROM emu 
ORDER BY ts ;
```

I don't know how this `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT()` function behaves with nulls. If there are `NULL` values in the checked for changes column - and you want to see if there is a change from the last non-null value and not just the previous one - the rewrite will be even more complicated.

---

**Edit:** As far as I understand Redshift's documentation an explicit window frame (`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`) is required for window aggregates when there is an `ORDER BY`. So, you can/have to use that (or whatever the default frame is in Vertica for these cases. It's either the above or with `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`).