# Row number/rank with "particular partition"

Tags: sql, group-by, case, rank, row-number

The table is this
[image]

The row_number in this is wrong, I want to to compute it in order to group the dates by real weeks (from monday to sunday), i.e.
1 for the first 4 rows, 2 for rows from 5 to 8, 3 for rows from 9 to 13 and so on. Maybe this can be solve with rank, but notice the desired column not always is determined by the change in year_week. The resulting table would be:
[image]

Comment: From the terminology perspective you are describing `rank` and not `row_number`.  Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number

Comment: Ok, with the name of the desired column I didn't want to meaning the function to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for close the answer...
After some searching I found this problem can ve solve with the function CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(), this is not implemented in all SQL lenguages, but can be explicited. Check [Is there any alternative to Vertica's conditional_true_event in RedShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606673/is-there-any-alternative-to-verticas-conditional-true-event-in-redshift) for more information.